# Wie viele Bedeutungen kann "fällt mit ab" haben?

Tags: phrase

Ich habe "fällt mit ab" im folgendem Kontext gesehen:

> Option 1 wird vorhanden sein, deswegen fällt Option 2 mit ab.

Ich habe es so verstanden, dass nur Option 1 vorhanden sein wird, und man deswegen Option 2 gar nicht haben wird. Ein Muttersprachler hat mich aber darauf hingewiesen, dass es nicht "verschwindet durch abfallen" bedeutet, sondern "ist automatisch mit dabei".

Kann dieser Ausdruck mehrere, eventuell andere, hier nicht erwähnte Bedeutungen haben?

Comment: Sorry, aber der Satz ist für mich als Muttersprachler vollkommen unverständlich, ergibt keinerlei Sinn...

Comment: Ich kann Torsten nur Recht geben: Dieser Satz ist, so wie er da steht, völlig unverständlich. Möglicherweise ergibt er mehr Sinn, wenn man den Kontext, in dem er verwendet wird, kennt. Aber diesen Kontext müsstest du uns erst mal verraten.

Comment: Könntest du geographisch eventuell etwas präzisieren, D/Ö/Swz etc?

Comment: Ich denke, das Verständnisproblem des OP liegt bei "abfallen" im eigentlichen Wortsinn von wegfallen, herunterfallen und dem Begriff "mit abfallen" im Sinne - wie Christian in seiner Antwort geschrieben hat - nicht beabsichtigter Nebennutzen.

Comment: @abbabab : D, und Hessen

Comment: Doch, man kann den Satz so verstehen, wie in den Antworten unten erläutert, also im Sinne des englischen Wortes _spin-off_. Ich glaube nicht, daß es sich um eine regionale Spezialität handelt.

Answer (score 2):

Wie die Kommentatoren anmerkten: Ohne weiteren Kontext muss man hier etwas herumraten.

Am ehesten fände ich ein Szenario realistisch, in dem gemeint ist:

> Wenn Option 1 eintritt, tritt automatisch auch Option 2 ein.

Beispiel: Wenn Bernd zur Party kommt, kommt automatisch auch Helga.

Das wäre dann eigentlich im Sinne wie deine muttersprachliche Gewährsperson schon sagte: "ist automatisch mit dabei" oder, etwas präziser vielleicht: "es entsteht dadurch folgender nicht direkt intendierte Nebennutzen."

Beispiele:

> "Wenn du das Faltblatt bei Druckerei Müller machen lässt, fällt vielleicht noch ein schöner goldner Kugelschreiber für dich ab."
>
> "Warum sollte ich bei dieser Aktion mitmachen? Da fällt doch nichts ab für mich dabei."

Eine andere Bedeutung von "fällt mit ab" fällt mir nicht ein.

Problematisch ist dabei freilich die Wahl des Wortes "Option". Denn wenn eines mit dem anderen quasi gesetzmäßig verbunden ist (wie Bernd mit Helga), ist es ja keine Option (Wahlmöglichkeit) mehr. Außer man hat kompliziertere Binnenbeziehungen wie etwa: "Wir können Bernd einladen, und wir können unabhängig davon Helga einladen. Wenn wir Bernd einladen, kommt Helga automatisch. Wenn wir Helga einladen, kommt sie erst mal alleine."

Comment: Bezüglich "Option": Im Originaltext waren dort zwei sehr technische Wörter die ich auf "Option" getauscht habe. Im Kontext haben aber beide Wörter eigentlich Optionen beschrieben.

Comment: Was waren denn die technischen Wörter? Ich vermute nämlich, dass "Option 2" eine Art Abfallprodukt ist, das immer dann entsteht, wenn "Option 1" vorhanden ist. Also etwa "Bronze wird vorhanden sein, deswegen fällt Hochofenschlacke mit ab" oder so ähnlich...

Comment: Was mir noch als mögliches Auftreten von "mit abfallen" einfallen würde, wäre ein Satz wie "Wenn die Äpfel vom Baum geschüttelt werden, fallen viele Blätter mit ab". Aber in dieser Verwendung im Sinne von "ebenfalls" kann sich "mit" ziemlich vielen Verben beigesellen.

Comment: @scienceponder : Nein, es hat nichts mit physikalische Abfallen zu tun.

Comment: "Denn wenn eines mit dem anderen quasi gesetzmäßig verbunden ist (wie Bernd mit Helga), ist es ja keine Option (Wahlmöglichkeit) mehr." - ich denke, du siehst das zu absolut. Was beispielsweise der Händler als zwei voneinander unabhängige Optionen präsentiert, könnte bei genauerem Hinsehen eine Sparversion und eine Luxusausführung sein, wobei Letztere Erstere faktisch mit abdeckt. Ebenso könnte das, was sich ein Auftraggeber als zwei unabhängige Produktmerkmale vorstellt, von einem findigen Ingenieur so gelöst werden, dass mit derselben Lösung fast ohne Zusatzaufwand beides erfüllt wird.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper   Ja... oder siehst nun du das wiederum zu liberal? Natürlich gibt es Situationen wie von dir geschildert, also z.B. ich kann einen Traktor mit Allradantrieb kaufen oder einen Traktor ohne Allradantrieb. Wenn ich nun den Traktor mit Allradantrieb kaufe, kaufe ich natürlich - sozusagen - auch den Traktor ohne Allradantrieb dazu (er fällt für mich ab dabei), aber das ist ja nur eine umständliche Spitzfindigkeit. Eigentlich kaufe ich halt den Traktor mit Allradantrieb, und nichts fällt dabei ab. (Ich spreche natürlich von zuschaltbarem Allradantrieb.)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: "Eigentlich kaufe ich halt den Traktor mit Allradantrieb" - das mag sein, dass man das beim Traktor so sagen würde. Im Telekommunikationsbereich ist aber die Wortwahl mit den (sich überlappenden) Optionen (leider?) relativ üblich, beispielsweise [hier](http://www.telekom.de/zuhause/tarife-und-optionen/zubuchoptionen/internet-optionen). Davon abgesehen ist das aber in der Tat kein typischer Fall, in dem ich "mit abfallen" verwenden würde - das bezieht sich häufig eher auf nicht so offensichtliche Überschneidungen von Leistungen.

Answer (score 1):

> Option 1 wird vorhanden sein, deswegen fällt Option 2 mit ab.

Zunächst: Vielleicht ist es etwas Regionales, aber mir als südwestdeutschem Muttersprachler ist auf den ersten Blick klar, was hier gemeint ist. Es ist interessant zu wissen, dass diese Formulierung offenbar nicht durchgehend verstanden wird.

Generell bedeutet *abfallen*, dass etwas sich von seinem Ursprungsort löst (dies wird hier durch die Vorsilbe *ab* ausgedrückt), somit von nichts mehr gehalten wird und ungebremst fällt. Im weiteren Sinn bedeutet es, dass etwas ohne weitere Anstrengung zum Fallen gebracht wird.

Damit sind wir auch schon praktisch bei der gängigen Bedeutung für *mit abfallen*, die dir genannt wurde: Wird Option 1 umgesetzt, bedarf es keines zusätzlichen Aufwands mehr, um auch Option 2 umzusetzen (und somit beide zu erhalten). Das *Fallen* ruft dabei die Assoziation mit einem Produkt hervor, das z.B. auf das Kassenband, den Einkaufskorb oder ganz allgemein in den "Herrschaftsbereich" eines Benutzers fällt.

Dennoch ist freilich auch die wörtliche Bedeutung von *mit abfallen* üblich, wenn sich das Verb rein auf physische Objekte bezieht (also nicht wie in deinem Produkt-/Angebots-bezogenen Beispiel). In dem Fall fällt etwas ab (es löst sich und fällt hinunter), und ein anderes Ding löst sich und fällt zeitgleich.

Beachte, dass die Nähe zum Wort *der Abfall* eher irreführend ist. Wenn Option 2 gestrichen wird, *fällt* sie statt dessen *weg*.